# Как распарсить XHTML-файлы на Java?

Tags: java, парсер

С помощью *xml-парсера(DOM)* пытаюсь распарсить файлы такого типа: view-source:https://www.yandex.ru/ 
Но не получается. Например, есть теги `meta` и не самозакрывающиеся, и не имеющие закрывающего их тега.
Как справиться с этой проблемой? Можно ли перевести из *xhtml* в *xml*, например?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте специальные фреймворки для этого, например [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: По-моему, вообще ни один живой сайт не распарсится XHTML парсером, как валидный.

Comment: @andy.37 ну например шарповый HAP спокойно парсит даже весьма кривую верстку.

Comment: питоновский BeautifulSoap тоже, но только в режиме HTML (без икса). А тут XML парсить пытаются.